# Best way to use simple asynchronous queues in django?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, queue, celery

I need my django view function to trigger a task which will then run in the background, not blocking the response.

```
def my_task(client_information, unique_id): # task
    #do something that takes a while

def my_view(request): # django view

    client_information = request.GET.get('whatever') # get some information passed from the client
    unique_id = generate_unique_id() # generate a unique ID for this task
    start_task(client_information, unique_id) # the interesting part: start the task with client information and unique id, but non blocking
    return JsonResponse({'id': unique_id})
```

I read about celery, but the code I saw looked overkill as I don't need any further communication between the processes and I really want a as lightweight as possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django Background Tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a simple database-based queue that only needs a worker running in the background (it's invoked through `manage.py process_tasks`). If you will never make use of Celery's benefits, I think this is the lightweight solution you're looking for.

Once you install the extension, you can define a method and add a `@background(schedule=20)` decorator to them, which will make them run in the background automatically. See [upstream docs](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted this answer as I think it proposes a valid solution for my problem. For now, I am trying to use this http://peter-hoffmann.com/2012/python-simple-queue-redis-queue.html to solve the problem. If I run into issues or am not satisfied with the result, I will use this solution.